# Center UIRefreshControl on UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I usually use a `UITableViewController` for working with tables but I need some extra stuff around the table so I used a `UIViewController` and had a `UITableView` in it. I found the following code to implement refreshing in that table.

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadSort) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

But there is one problem I am having. ***The refresh control is not centered over the table.*** How would I get the `refreshControl` to be centered over the table? Should I do this a different way?

Comment: For your information UIRefreshControl will automatically get in centre of UITableview.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was my table view was not correctly contained to be centered in my `UIViewController`.

After using auto layout to "Add Missing Constraints" the refresh control is now directly in the middle.